# Processing dialog for SharePoint 2013 remote event receiver -Item Added event

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Is it possible to have a dialog, "Waiting for the Item to be added" for SharePoint 2013 custom list to which a remote event receiver is attached (Provider hosted app with App installed event), having an ItemAdded event. If an item is added, now the list add item page is seen as stuck, instead a user friendly dialog "Please wait for the item to be added" need to be displayed.

Any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :)

```
// BEGIN long-running operation
SPLongOperation lop = new SPLongOperation(this.Page);
lop.LeadingHTML = "<div><h2>Your enormous file is being uploaded...</h2></div>";
lop.TrailingHTML = "<div><h3>Please be patient</h3></div>";
lop.Begin();

// your long operation code here

// END long-running operation
lop.End(spTargetListObject.DefaultViewUrl, Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPRedirectFlags.Default, this.Context, "");
```

Here'a a helpful blog about it http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-programatically-show-processing.html